# FlexBox with Image and Text, force the text to linebreak not the image

Tags: html, css

Im working with a widget and so the length of my text is dynamic . I figured out how to line break in flex box but its not exactly doing what its supposed to . 
The text - line break  is now working properly but the Image changes its position.

[image]

This is all right, but when I type in more text and force the linebreak it does this: [image]

If I enter even more text it "jumps" back to the desired position. 
[image]

```css
.picture{
    margin:0;
    float:right;
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto; 
}

.Container{
    display:inline-flex;
    align-items: baseline;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
    vertical-align: top;
    word-break: break-all;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container"> <p class="jobDescription">{{job}}</p> <img src="{{bildHaus}}" alt="bildHaus" class="picture"></div>
```

I dont want the image to "jump" to the left upper corner. 
Thanks for reading this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I understood what you're trying to achieve. If you want to keep your text always on the left side of the picture, try this way:

```css
.picture{
    margin:0;
    float:right;
    max-width:50%;
    height:auto; 
}

.Container{
    display:inline-flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: no-wrap;
    vertical-align: top;
    word-break: break-all;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

p {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container"> <p class="jobDescription">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p> <img src="https://www.voyagesphotosmanu.com/Complet/images/immagine_geranio_gr.jpg" alt="bildHaus" class="picture"></div>
```

I edited the code so both img and text take up to the 50% of the viewport size and the text is aligned to the top of the image.
If this is not what you want just go back to:

```
.picture{
    max-width:100%;
}
```

and

```
.Container{
    align-items: baseline;
}
```

Comment: Thank you it looks way better now ! Have a nice day Erik !

Answer (score 0):

```css
.picture{
    max-width: 50%; /*try to modify the width, enjoy!*/
    width: 100%;
    height:auto; 
}

.Container{
    display: flex;
}

p {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
  <p class="jobDescription">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <img src="https://www.voyagesphotosmanu.com/Complet/images/immagine_geranio_gr.jpg" alt="bildHaus" class="picture">
</div>
```

This is my answer of your problem. I think you have a lot of useless CSS. With flex, you just need to flex the child , and define the max-width to control.
Width flex: 1; on the text , you can modify the size of the picture to manage the size of text. 
I hope this will help you !